# How can I easily view the content of DataTable or DataSet in Visual Studio Code for dotnet core?

Tags: .net, .net-core, visual-studio-code

There is a dataset visualizer that comes up with Visual Studio. But while debugging projects in **Visual Studio Code** there is no quick or easy option to see DataSet/DataTable content.

Can anyone please suggest any DataSet/DataTable visualizer for Visual Studio Code?